# 7zip - How to create archive of directory contents with right click menu

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I want to be able to right click on a directory in windows explorer and create an archive with that directories content named after the directory.

Thus:

MyStuff

MyStuff.zip

The problem I have is that archive contains a top level directory MyStuff. I don't want this. I just want the contents of MyStuff.

Is it possible to configure the shell extension to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the directory, press Ctrl-A or use the mouse to select all the items in the directory, and *then* right click and go to the shell extension menu.

When you go to the context menu with multiple items selected it defaults to the parent directory for the archive name and seems to be what you are after.

For me this achieves pretty much what you want with only one extra step.